# Could not load timestamp from dataprep to bigquery

Tags: timestamp, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I am scheduling a **DataPrep** job for aggregation purposes. The job just consolidates the raw data from **Bigquery** and put it back into another bigquery table. There is a **timestamp** column (which is used as the partitioning key for table partitioning) in the recipe, but the following error comes while trying to run the job.

> Note that columns that aren't Integer, Float, or Boolean will get converted to String.

I cannot update the datatype in bigquery because this column is used as the partitioning key(which should be either in date/timestamp format). How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the column data types on the [column information](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Data-Grid-Panel_57344857#column-information)? Keep in mind that you can change the column data type, in this case to [Datetime](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Datetime-Data-Type_57344795) by using the [Settype transform](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Settype-Transform_57344649#top_of_page) too.